# File Browser - missing an input box

Tags: interface, file-browser

I should have another box below the one circled.  The box I need has a plus and minus sign next to it.  Searched high and low for the setting but no joy!

[image]

I opened the Editor Type in top left of window to the File Browser window. I located my desktop folder and set up a New Folder here. In the instructional video I watched he then enters a further piece of text in the box below the file name box. The text he enters ends in an underscore like this _. I believe its called a partial. I can't do this as there's no box in which to input this text

Comment: Hi. What are you expecting this extra box to do? How did you open the file browser? Thanks.

Comment: I opened the Editor Type in top left of window to the File Browser window.  I located my desktop folder and set up a New Folder here.  In the instructional video I watched he then enters a further piece of text in the box below the file name box.  The text he enters ends in an underscore like this _.  I believe its called a partial. I can't do this as there's no box in which to input this text

Answer (score 3):

The box you are looking for is the file name box, where you input the file name for the undergoing operation. Those buttons allow to increment or decrement the file numbering automatically

If you open the *File Browser* as a regular editor, there is no "default file action", it just open for view and navigation purposes, and as such the file name box is unavailable because there is no active operation to preform.

To have the name box available and the increment/decrement visible, the file manager has to be invoked from a menu to preform some IO action, rather than a permanently open browser part of the workspace layout.

[image: d]

If you go to *File > Import* or *File > Save as* or any other file operation like linking, appending, exporting, or any other operation that requires specifying a file the name box will show, along with the buttons.